# Jenkins failure job: Jenkins can't cd to specific path

Tags: jenkins, jobs

I am novice with Jenkins, I am trying to create a Job.
For build I use "execute shell command" and the code is as below:
cd /Users/username/javaFiles
javac hello.java
java -cp . hello

however, when Build the job, i got this failure message : [image: failureMessage]

Thanks in advance for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path for **cd** is correct ? Ensure the path exist.

Comment: Yes, it exists !! :/

Comment: I also verified files permissions !!

Comment: Is this a Jenkinsfile? Maybe you could try an ls command to see what's in that directory

Comment: it's a new item, I selected a freestyle project and then I put this code in the build section "execute shell", I am following and example on youtube and it works perfectly. I don't understand why it fails for me..!

Comment: Show me the tutorial

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RNeYmD9mJpU&ab_channel=ProgrammingKnowledge

Comment: What system do you use ? windows or linux ?

Comment: I use macOS sysstem

Comment: I tried this solution: jhome () {
cd /Users/thourayasboui/javaFiles/
javac hello.java
java -cp . hello

}  the status is success now but the "hello world!" output message still absent

Comment: I will ask the right question

On which system do you have your jenkins server installed?

Comment: jenkins is running as an image on docker  localy installed  and I have access to jenkins using the browser via the "localhost:8080" URL

Comment: If it is a container you should share that path by mounting a volume to access it from inside container.

Comment: how please?? I am new with jenkins and docker environment, thanks !

Comment: I have this tutorial https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mounting-a-volume-inside-docker-container/ when you have mounted everything you should point the execution from the mounted volume to the cd command

Comment: I'm glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have given permission..run below cmd:

chmod 777 Users/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).